# Some trouble with unity scripting

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Have next trouble in Unity C#
Setting variable to script from another and check its changing in Update method
Its changing once and returning to previous value 
i initialize this variable before any method
some example of code which i try

```
public class someclass: MonoBehaviour
{
    public int myvariable=1; 
    void Update()
    {
        print(myvariable);
    }
}
```

When i change it from another script i get that value only once
I can't understand where can be my problem

changing by next

```
public class someanotherclass: MonoBehaviour
{
    void someEvent()
    {
        someclass changing=GetComponent<someclass>();
        changing.myvariable=2;
    }
}
```

Comment: Nothing in your posted code suggests the problem you are describing, have you included everything?

Comment: this is everything))
i make simple project on this case and have same result 
But on my PC it's work fine

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding your issue, are you saying that the value of myvariable is being set back to 1? Make sure these components/scripts only exist on one object just for clarity.

Comment: yep
I'm looking trace of my console:
So in update function my trace has next character:
1 .... then 2(after event method calling) then 1Something like this 1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,1,1.....

Comment: Are both scripts attached to the same object?